# ExtJS Filtering Combobox Store

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, filter, combobox

I have the following Combobox declared:

```
{
   xtype: 'combobox',
   id:'sizeSelect',
   store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
       fields: [
                   {name: 'typeChoosen', type: 'string'},
                   {name: 'sizeValue',  type: 'string'}
       ],
       data: [
           ['DECIMAL','(9.2)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(9.4)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(19.2)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(19.4)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(28.2)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(28.4)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(38.2)'],
           ['DECIMAL','(38.4)'],
           ['TEXT','250'],
           ['TEXT','500'],
           ['TEXT','1000'],
           ['TEXT','2000'],
           ['TEXT','4000'],
           ['INTEGER','dafault']
        ]
    })
}
```

I use it in a panel with a grid, for the column "size":

[image]

I want the combobox in column 'size' to be updated based on the previous cell value, with the corresponding values for each type.

In the grid panel I have the following listener that I use for the filtering:

```
listeners : {
beforeitemdblclick : function( eventThis,  record,  item, index, e, eOpts,objA ){

    var stateCombo = Ext.getCmp('sizeSelect');
    var currentTypeChoosen = record.raw[1]
    stateCombo.store.each(function(storeItem){
            if(storeItem.data.typeChoosen == currentTypeChoosen){ 
                stateCombo.store.filter("typeChoosen",currentTypeChoosen);
            }                                           
    }); 
}
```

It seems to compare it right, but it returns an object in the combobox instead of just the values. I'm pretty new to ExtJS and I really can't think of a way to make it work as I want to.

**UPDATE**

This is my working code:

```
{
xtype: 'combobox',
id:'sizeSelect',
editable:false,
valueField: 'typeValue',
displayField: 'typeValue',
mode:'local',
lastQuery: '',
allowBlank: false,
listeners:{
},
store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: ['size', 'typeValue'],
    data: [
            ['DECIMAL', '(9,2)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(9,4)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(19,2)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(19,4)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(28,2)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(28,4)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(38,2)'],
            ['DECIMAL', '(38,4)'],
            ['TEXT', '250'],
            ['TEXT', '500'],
            ['TEXT', '1000'],
            ['TEXT', '2000'],
            ['TEXT', '4000']
        ]
})
}

var panel3 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', { 
    id:'step3',
    border:0,
    xtype: 'panel', 
    anchor:'100% 100%',
    hideMode:'display',
    bodyStyle:"overflow-y:scroll !important;",
    hidden:true,
    autoHeight:true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        id:'tableTypeGrid',
        border: false,                      
        plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 2
            })
        ],
        listeners : {
            beforeitemdblclick : function( eventThis,  record,  item, index, e, eOpts ){
                var stateSizeCombo = Ext.getCmp('sizeSelect');
                var sizeColumnStore = stateSizeCombo.getStore();
                var prevCellValue = record.data.type;
                sizeColumnStore.clearFilter();
                sizeColumnStore.filter('size', prevCellValue); //
                }
            },
            ...
```

The properties of the combobox turned out to be very important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`beforeedit`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing.html#event-beforeedit) event for grid (added from [Ext.grid.plugin.Editing](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing)), like this:

```
    beforeedit: function(plugin, context) {
        // Current editor panel size combo
        var sizeCombo = plugin.editor.down('combo[name=size]');
        if(sizeCombo) {
            var sizeStore = sizeCombo.getStore();
            sizeStore.clearFilter();
            sizeStore.filter('type', context.record.get('type'));
        }
    }
```

Check this [simple example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mte).

Comment: Thanks! The example is really helpful. I will try it later and I hope it will be also working with my code, cause the latest version of ext I can use is 4.0. :/ So it's questionable.

Comment: @Nyagolova, sure, check it out! Actually Im working with ExtJS 4 aswell and I was reading ExtJS 4 docs to answer your question so I believe it should work with ExtJS 4+. If not - ask me here.

Comment: I'm gonna accept it, because you answer helped me a lot (even though it wasn't implemented the same in my code) and the fiddle is actually working! :)